# JSON.Net in Api controllers w/ param containing Dictionary is always null

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I've seen some tutorials out there that claim to work, but they are outdated or simply do not work.

How can I use JSON.Net to serialize and deserialize the data received to and sent from my API controllers?

We are using VS2012.

#### Update

I have a model like this

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Terms { get; set; }
}
```

And an Api controller like this

```
public class ModelSearchApiController : ApiController
{

     public List<Model> Get([FromUri] SearchModel search)
     {
         return new List<Model>();
     }
}
```

However, `search` provides the correct value set in the Ajax request, the property `Terms` is always an empty dictionary.

I know we can provide a value like `[ { Key:"foo", Value:123 } ]` but why can't I just pass a normal JSON object (ie `{ foo:123 }`) ??? Why can it serialize a `Dictionary` into a nice standard JSON object, but cannot take that **exact** same object and recreate a `Dictionary`. This is beyound me.

#### Edit

In other words, if the browser sends these arguments :

```
 pageIndex: 0
 pageSize: 100
 terms[foo]: Bar
 terms[buz]: 1234
```

What would be the required object signature? Because the object mentionned above does not work and the dictionary is just empty.

Comment: JSON.NET is the default serializer for API controllers (i.e., classes derived from `ApiController`). You don't need to do anything else, it should just work. Are you having any specific issues?

Comment: @carlosfigueira, yes. One of my model declare a `JsonConverter` and the deserializer doesn't use it. This let's me assume that Json.net is *not* used for deserializing my data.

Comment: @ckozl, I am sorry to tell you this, but whatever people say, Json.Net is definitely **NOT** the default serializer. The default serializer gives an awful non-standard pseudo-JSON response for an object (but still manage to serialize a dictionary right). And I just replaced it with my own. The problem is that **it does not read** from the request anything.

Comment: Again, JSON.NET is the default serializer for API controllers. If you define a JsonConverter, it will be used - for **JSON input**. See my answer for more complete details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON.NET **is the default serializer** for ASP.NET Web API - it can convert between **JSON** and CLR objects, and does so for all JSON input. However, you're not trying to convert a JSON input to your SearchModel - you're trying to convert from the URI-based format which is similar to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, into the CLR type SearchModel, and that is not supported by JSON.NET (it's not JSON!). In general, the serializers are used to convert (on incoming requests) from the *request body* to the action parameter.

Let's look at this (complete) example below (assuming the default route, to `"api/{controller}"`). It's very similar to your question, but I also added a Post method in addition to the GET method.

```
public class ModelSearchApiController : ApiController
{
    public List<Model> Get([FromUri] SearchModel search)
    {
        return new List<Model>
        {
            new Model { PageIndex = search.PageIndex, PageSize = search.PageSize, Terms = search.Terms }
        };
    }

    public List<Model> Post(SearchModel search)
    {
        return new List<Model>
        {
            new Model { PageIndex = search.PageIndex, PageSize = search.PageSize, Terms = search.Terms }
        };
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Terms { get; set; }
}

public class SearchModel
{
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Terms { get; set; }
}
```

If you send this request to the server:

```
POST http://localhost:64699/api/ModelSearchApi HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:64699
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 65

{"PageIndex":1,"PageSize":10,"Terms":{"foo":"bar","foo2":"bar2"}}
```

It will be bound, as you expect, to the SearchModel parameter - the `Terms` property will be a dictionary with two entries (foo=bar, foo2=bar2).

Now, for the GET parameter. ASP.NET Web API has a concept of [*model binders*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.modelbinding.imodelbinder%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and [*value provider*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.valueproviders.ivalueprovider%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), which would be the component which would convert between the query string into the action parameters. The default binder / provider do not support the "arbitrary" name/value pair syntax *for dictionary inside complex types. You can, as you pointed out, use the key/value pair syntax, and that will be understood, as shown below.

```
GET http://localhost:64699/api/ModelSearchApi?PageIndex=1&PageSize=10&Terms[0][key]=foo&Terms[0][value]=bar HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:64699
```

Now, for your problem you have two options. You can change your API to use a custom model binder or value provider which knows how to understand the "simple" name/value syntax, as shown below:

```
public class ModelSearchApiController : ApiController
{
    public List<Model> Get([ModelBinder(typeof(MySearchModelBinder))] SearchModel search)
    {
        return new List<Model>
        {
            new Model { PageIndex = search.PageIndex, PageSize = search.PageSize, Terms = search.Terms }
        };
    }
}

public class MySearchModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        SearchModel value = new SearchModel();
        value.Terms = new Dictionary<string,object>();
        foreach (var queryParams in actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs())
        {
            if (queryParams.Key == "PageIndex")
            {
                value.PageIndex = int.Parse(queryParams.Value);
            }
            else if (queryParams.Key == "PageSize")
            {
                value.PageSize = int.Parse(queryParams.Value);
            }
            else if (queryParams.Key.StartsWith("Terms."))
            {
                value.Terms.Add(queryParams.Key.Substring("Terms.".Length), queryParams.Value);
            }
        }

        bindingContext.Model = value;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Another option is to pre-process your input data on the client prior to sending to the server, using a function similar to the one below.

```
function objToKVPArray(obj) {
    var result = [];
    var k;
    for (k in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            result.push({ key: k, value: obj[k] });
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why everyone says that JSON.Net is the default JsonFormatter. For me, I had to replace it because using the default formatter gave invalid JSON notations *and* did not understand the JSON.Net's class/properties attributes. Anyhow, moving on. I needed to have the same output as the input for my models (what I get from the server should be same that I send back to it), therefore I simply used a custom class extending `Dictionary<string, TModel>` and having a `[JsonArrayAttribute]`. This allowed me to have the (ugly and non-standard) array of object `{key, value}` that C# understand.

Comment: If you propose a solution to allow standard JSON objects to be passed as a `Dictionary` to C# using your [value provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.valueproviders.ivalueprovider%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), then I'll check your answer as the accepted solution. As for now, this is merely a hack as I don't like this solution (key/value pairs instead of a real JSON object)

Comment: Let's set some terminology, I think we're talking different things. JSON is a wire format. A "JSON object" is something in this format: `{"name":<value>}`, where `<value>` can be a string, number, Boolean, null or another JSON object or array. The input that the GET action receives is not a JSON object. It's a translation of a *JavaScript* object into a name/value-pair notation...

Comment: I'm curious to see the example where you say that the default formatter is generating invalid JSON - could you send an example to carlosfigueira at outlook dot com? If this is the case, it should be a bug in the framework, and I know some people who work on the ASP.NET team, and I'd be glad to pass it along to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference the [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/18/using-json-net-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx) below. Hope this help.

And here is [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-JSONNET-with-ASPNET-b2423706) using Json.net with web API.

Comment: The link you provided does not work, or at least doesn't seem to work. It references things that no longer exists with VS2012.

Comment: alright, I managed to make it work by replacing some methods signature, but the deserializer does not seem to work. I'll update the question to reflect what I'm trying to do